# C#, Using "-" to add arguements for exe ran via CMD

Tags: c#, cmd, arguments, exe

Absolutely no C# experience here but been asked to edit a Windows Form Application and got a little stuck!

Upon clicking a button on the form the following coding runs:

```
private void RunHPPreSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/k C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Exstream\HP Exstream 8.0.310\Engine.exe");            
}
```

This works fine but I need to add in an arguments to allow Engine.exe to grab settings for a control file. I have tried changing the code to:

```
private void RunHPPreSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/k C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Exstream\HP Exstream 8.0.310\Engine.exe -CONTROLFILE=C:\Users\adam.pope\Desktop\Accenture\Control Files\Accenture Control File Step One.opt");            
}
```

I did this because running `C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Exstream\HP Exstream 8.0.310\Engine.exe -CONTROLFILE=C:\Users\adam.pope\Desktop\Accenture\Control Files\Accenture Control File Step One.opt` directly from the Command Line works perfectly. However when I use it through the Windows Form Application I get the following error in the on the Command Line:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch files.
```

It seems that adding the "-" in before the arguments is causing the problem but this is the only way in which `Engine.exe` will accept arguments.

Is there a solution to this? Sorry if it is blindingly obvious but I have no idea what I'm doing in the C# world!

Comment: I have tried using differing number of quotes to close the 2nd argument with no success.

Comment: An answer was added but then removed which solved my problem, credit to whoever it was that added it! Thanks, Adam.

Comment: Could you add the answer yourself for future users?   Was it putting more " quotes in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it was working before without any quotes, because cmd wouldn't run it if it had unquoted spaces.

Try using this instead

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k \"C:\\Program Files\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP Exstream\\HP Exstream 8.0.310\\Engine.exe\" -CONTROLFILE=C:\\Users\\adam.pope\\Desktop\\Accenture\\Control Files\\Accenture Control File Step One.opt");
```

You may have to quote the parameter as well, but that depends on how the program you are calling handles arguments with spaces.